# How can I define the right namespacing for ex_admin and phoenix >=1.3.0-rc

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
Phoenix 1.3.0-rc function MyApp.Router.Helpers.admin_path/3 is undefined
```

All routes of ex_admin wont work after upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin/issues/321

adjust your config, the path is concatinated within utils.ex.
this might also help for other libraries.

config/config.exs

```
config :ex_admin,
  repo: MyApp.Repo,
  module: MyApp.Web
```